# loading pretrained model in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, pytorch

First, I'd like to apologize this question may sound stupid but I'm new to deep learning. Can anybody explain to me the following lines of code which was used to load the pre-trained model in PyTorch?

```
# Retrieving model parameters from checkpoint.
vocab_size = checkpoint["model"]["_word_embedding.weight"].size(0)
embedding_dim = checkpoint["model"]['_word_embedding.weight'].size(1)
hidden_size = checkpoint["model"]["_projection.0.weight"].size(0)
num_classes = checkpoint["model"]["_classification.4.weight"].size(0)
```

I can't understand the projection, weight, classification, size(0), size(1) in the above text.

Comment: It's probably better to check out some tutorials on pytorch to figure out what the code does rather than asking here.

Comment: why is `torch.load` not sufficient for your case? What research have you done?

Answer (score 0):

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class Model(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()

        vocab_size = 10000
        embed_size = 100
        # word embedding layer
        self._word_embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size)
        # linear transformation layers (no bias)
        self._projection = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(100, 50, bias=False)
                                          for i in range(2)])
        # linear transformation layers (no bias)
        self._classification = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(50, 50, bias=False)
                                              for i in range(4)])

    def forward(self):
        return


model = Model()
checkpoint = {
    'model': model.state_dict()  # OrderedDict
}

# _word_embedding.weight --> torch.Size([10000, 100])
# _projection.0.weight --> torch.Size([50, 100])
# _projection.1.weight --> torch.Size([50, 100])
# _classification.0.weight --> torch.Size([50, 50])
# _classification.1.weight --> torch.Size([50, 50])
# _classification.2.weight --> torch.Size([50, 50])
# _classification.3.weight --> torch.Size([50, 50])

for name, param in checkpoint['model'].items():
    print(name, '-->', param.size()) # see above

# similarly, we can print as follows
print(checkpoint["model"]["_word_embedding.weight"].size(0)) # 10000
print(checkpoint["model"]["_word_embedding.weight"].size(1)) # 100
print(checkpoint["model"]["_projection.0.weight"].size(0)) # 50
print(checkpoint["model"]["_classification.0.weight"].size(0)) # 50
```

Prepared an example to help you understand the meaning of those four lines.

> I can't understand the projection, weight, classification, size(0), size(1) in the above text.

- **projection**: a neural network layer
- **classification**: a neural network layer
- **weight**: the weight matrix of the respective NN layers
- **size(0)**: the size of the first dimension of the weight matrix
- **size(1)**: the size of the second dimension of the weight matrix